# How to add a list to the first row of csv files of a particular folder

Tags: python, csv

There is a folder named data containing multiple csv files but there are no headers to that csv file and hence I have to add headers to the first row of the multiple csv files .

I have the below code which is taking one csv file and adding the list to the last row. I need it to the first row and instead of taking one csv file , it must take all csv files from a folder at once. Can you please help me how to do it?

```
List = [" ", " "]
with open('.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_object:  
    # Pass the CSV  file object to the writer() function
    writer_object = writer(f_object)
    # Result - a writer object
    # Pass the data in the list as an argument into the writerow() function
    writer_object.writerow(List)  
    # Close the file object
    f_object.close()
```

Comment: You cannot insert into a file in place.  You should read the whole file, close it, open it for writing, write your header, then write the data.  You don't need the CSV module for this.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the CSV module.

```
for fn in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    contents = open(fn).read()
    with open(fn,'w') as f:
        print("header1,header2,header3", file=f)
        f.write(contents)
```